# Rebase commits before a merging point

Tags: git, merge, rebase

A Mercurial repo has been converted into a GIT repo after doing a lot of local commits on a different head and pulling the latest main head commits from the remote. (hereafter referred as 'their commits') Becausue the tip was on my head after conversion I ended up with a new GIT repo where a branch contained 'their commits' and the master contained my commits. I merged that branch into the master to adopt 'their commits' and deleted the branch. But when I rebase the master only the commits after the merge and 'their commits' before the merge can be edited, but not my commits before the merge.

Before conversion:

[image: Before conversion]

After conversion, merging and pushing some commits on master:

[image: after conversion, merging and pushing some commits on master]

If I want to rebase I cannot see my commits before the merge:

```
git checkout master
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

[image: rebase]

I expect to combine those commits:

```
cmake lists added for cmake
Link the mbed libraries in the cmake config
inlcluding fix stream.h
Cmake testing
```

Because they are all related to each other and are just a matter of adding some small config files.
I do not find an option to 'select' in which direction to look for the rebase history in GIT.

Comment: It seems that mbed CLI 2 is not fully checking out the repo. The image above is from the folder I used to push the repo created. However even when doing a fresh checkout it's no evidence to do a rebase over a splitting point. Becasue I did not had many commits I made some backups, did a hard reset to breakup the merge  point, did the merge again, overwrote the files with the backup to solve the conficts and redid the merge. I moved the master branch and did new commits based on my second backup files. After all I did a force push. It's a bit tricky bit it worked.